# How to turn link to string in PHP

Tags: php

I am just beginning PHP and I am very confused

say

```
www.blablabla.com/phpfile.php?=this_is_a_test
```

I want to create a new string from text after the ?=

So in this case the string would be "this_is_a_test"

how would I do this?

Comment: Have a look at the [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/parse_url) function

Comment: Well the urls with query strings looks like this: www.example.com/file.php?param=value Then you can get the value also with $_GET

Answer (score 2):

Here is the example:

```
$url = 'www.blablabla.com/phpfile.php?=this_is_a_test';

print_r(parse_url($url));
```

Comment: but the .php file is supposed to get its own link. i can't supply a static string as the link will continue to change everytime an inquiry is made.

Comment: You adapt in your case, It is only simple example to show how it works.

Answer (score 1):

Use [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php):

```
$parsed = parse_url($url);
echo substr($parsed['query'], 1);
```

Output:

```
this_is_a_test
```

If you have multiple variables in the query, you can parse them like in the following example:

```
$url = 'www.blablabla.com/phpfile.php?foo=bar&baz=boom';
$parsed = parse_url($url);
parse_str($parsed['query'], $out);
print_r($out);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [foo] => bar
    [baz] => boom
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to use `$query = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];`